# getting error when i try to run react native app on android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to run react native app on android with this command `npx react-native run-android`

but i am getting this error every time:

> Failed to parse React Native CLI configuration. Expected running 'npx.cmd --quiet --no-install react-native config' command from 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\AppName' directory to output valid JSON, but it didn't. This may be caused by npx resolving to a legacy global react-native binary. Please make sure to uninstall any global 'react-native' binaries: 'npm uninstall -g react-native react-native-cli' and try again
>   **

how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

have u installed react native cli and react native globally?

Comment: i have already uninstalled them by this command:

 `npm uninstall -g react-native react-native-cli` 
but still getting the same error